# PHP: Fill PDF form

Tags: php, forms, pdf

I have a PDF document which contains form with couple of form fields. I need to do following:

- Load that PDF document
- Itearate through all the form fields of that document and fill it up with the data
- Download filled flatten document

I have seen few of libraries, but most of them are relying on the PDFtk. But the case is that I don't have the possibility to install PDFtk on the server.

Is there any library which allows such action and is "pure" php so I don't have to install anything on server?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [SetaPDF-FormFiller](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/details/) component for this task (not free! And I'm related to the company behind). Let `$data` be your array of data, a simple usage example would be:

```
// Load that PDF document
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename('path/to.pdf');
$formFiller = new SetaPDF_FormFiller($document);

// Itearate through all the form fields of that document and fill it up with the data
$fields = $formFiller->getFields();
foreach ($fields->getNames() as $fieldName) {
    $field = $fields->get($fieldName);
    $field->setValue($data[$fieldName]);
}

// flatten document
$fields->flatten();

// Download filled flatten document
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_Http('result.pdf');
$document->setWriter($writer);
$document->save()->finish();
```

It is all done in pure PHP and requires only common PHP extensions to be enabled (see [system requirements](https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-core-manual/installation/#index-1)).